# Как на WinForms создать произвольный scroll в datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

Возможно ли это? Или может можно программно изменить текущее положение уже существующего `VScrollBar`?

Answer (score 5):

`VScrollBar` можно покрутить, поменяв свойство [`VScrollBar.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.value(v=vs.110).aspx) на целочисленное значение между `VScrollBar.Minimum` и `VScrollBar.Maximum`.

Answer (score 1):

> может можно программно изменить текущее положение уже существующего VScrollBar?

Проще изменить значение DataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex.
Пример прокрутки DataGridView при нажатии кнопок в меню формы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
// Microsoft (R) Roslyn C# Compiler version 1.1.0.51204
#r "System.Windows.Forms"

using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;

var f = new Form() { Width = 600, Height = 250 };
var g = new DataGridView() { Parent=f, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
g.RowTemplate.Height = 40;
g.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(0, 50)
               .Select(v => new { Id = v, Data = DateTime.Now.Ticks })
               .ToList();
g.DataBindingComplete += (s, e) =>
    g.Columns[g.Columns.Count-1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
f.Menu = new MainMenu();
f.Menu.MenuItems.AddRange(new[] {
  new MenuItem("up", (s, e) => g.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex--),
  new MenuItem("down", (s, e) => g.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex++),
  new MenuItem("select", (s, e) => {
      g.ClearSelection();
      g.Rows[g.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex].Selected = true;
  })
});
f.ShowDialog();
```

---

Для компиляции кода и запуска приложения, например, в Visual Studio Community 2015 надо открыть `View - Other Windows - C# Interactive`, скопировать в него код и нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Visual Studio Community 2015 - бесплатная версия, ее можно скачать [тут](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146).